# Mapping two fields of the same class with One-to-One relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a `Flight` class and a `AircraftReport` class. The `AircraftReport` class contains an inbound flight and an outbound flight which I would both like to be mapped as a `@OneToOne`. How do I correctly define the relationship?

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table
public class Flight implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "flight_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "flight_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String callsign;
    private Date date;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    private String registration;
    private String aircraftType;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "--what should it be mapped by here--")
    private AircraftReport aircraftReport;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
public class AircraftReport implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "taxsheet_sequence"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "taxsheet_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inbound_flight_id")
    private Flight inboundFlight;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "outbound_flight_id")
    private Flight outboundFlight;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use mappedBy? Further: Do you need the bidirectional relationship? I currently do not fully understand what the use case is and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you don't need to use a bidirectional relationship for a `OneToOne` mapping. If you want the `AircraftReport` just get the `AircraftReport` and the `Flight` instances will come with it. Otherwise if you're not working with a report just get the `Flight` and be happy.

Also, I don't recommend using `Cascade` operations on a `OneToOne`, or at any time for that matter. Do you really ever want the `Flight` deleted?

Map to either `inboundFlight` or `outboundFlight`. You can't have one bidirectional relationship take the place of two of them. If you want two bidirectional relationships then add another to `Flight`.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "inboundFlight")
private AircraftReport aircraftReportInbound;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "outboundFlight")
private AircraftReport aircraftReportOutbound;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have two separate relationships from AircraftReport two Flight, you also have to separate relationships from Flight to AircraftReport.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "inboundFlight")
private AircraftReport aircraftReportInbound;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "outboundFlight")
private AircraftReport aircraftReportOutbound;
```

Comment: Why is this necessary? It can also work without defining the relationship on Flight

Comment: It's not necessary you can also remove these because they are not required. Only if you want to navigate from Flight to the AircraftReport in the code